# how to use regexp_extract in hive

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I am trying to extract a portion of the below string using regexp_extract but am not having any success:

> CUST_NEW_ACCOUNTS_LINES_2019-03-03.dat.gz

I want to just get the date portion.  On the regex101.com website this seemed to work, but hive is giving me an error message.

```
regexp_extract(meta_source_filename,'^(?:[^_]+_){4}([^_]+)') file_date
```

Can someone help me understand what is incorrect here?  I am not at all familiar with regexp_extract syntax so have been using another function as a starting point.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have captured the substring you need into a capturing group. You should use the number, ID of the group as the third argument:

```
regexp_extract(meta_source_filename,'^(?:[^_]+_){4}([^_]+)', 1) file_date
                                                             ^
```

See the [`regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) docs:

> The 'index' parameter is the Java regex Matcher group() method index. See [docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for more information on the 'index' or Java regex group() method.

Answer (score 2):

```
with your_data as (
select 'CUST_NEW_ACCOUNTS_LINES_2019-03-03.dat.gz' str
)

select regexp_extract(str,'_(\\d{4}(-\\d{2}){2})\\.',1)
from your_data;
```

Result:

```
OK
2019-03-03
Time taken: 0.062 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Expression `'_(\\d{4}(-\\d{2}){2})\\.'` means:

underscore `_`  four digits `\\d{4}` repeat (hyphen and two digits) two times `(-\\d{2}){2}` dot`\\.`

Capture group number one (date only): `(\\d{4}(-\\d{2}){2})` . 
In Hive you need to use `\\` for shielding.